# Bootstrap navbar search bar to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a navbar but when I try to resize the screen, at one point search bars comes below rather than collapsing. MY code is :

```
//row start
<div class="row">
   //navbar class with affix used in css
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                     <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a href="#">Life</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Tours and Travels</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                     <li>
                        <form style="float:right" class="navbar-form" role="search" aria-expanded="false">
                           <div class="input-group add-on">
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                              <div class="input-group-btn">
                                 <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                 </button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the 'More' dropdown you have there as a layout compromise and I just feel that more compromise is needed. I've condensed all menu links in a dropdown, on small screens.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                        </button>
                             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-sm">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                         <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Life</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Tours and Travels</a></li>         
                                    </ul>
                                </li>                               
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-md visible-lg">
                                <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Life</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Tours and Travels</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><form style="float:right" class="navbar-form" role="search" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <div class="input-group add-on">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```